# VueJS + Electron create debian installer doesn't work (electron-installer-debian)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, electron

I was working with VueJS to create a web application and I finally decide to change it into a desktop one. So i cloned my project and based on this QuickStart tutorial [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) I changed my Vue application into an Electron one.

But now that I have finished developing my software, I would like to create an installer of that and use it anywhere i want. And that's where the problems started.

This tutorial [Electron packager tutorial](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/) allowed me to create package of my application, and this one [Electron installer debian package](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-installer-debian-package/) allowed me to create the debian installer. But when the `.deb` file is generated and i execute it the size of the software is **0 byte** and the software won't launch after installing.

I did anything but i can't find where the problem is.

Here are some elements that can help people help me..

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "Sogemex_Industry_App",
  "productName": "Sogemex Industry App",
  "author": "Nanon <ouattarananon22@gmail.com>",
  "icon": "icon.png",
  "description": "Sogemex Industry work application",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . Sogemex_Industry_App --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=/home/nanon/Projets/VueJS/sogemex_electron/src/assets/sogemex-Industry.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . Sogemex_Industry_App --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=/home/nanon/Projets/VueJS/sogemex_electron/src/assets/sogemex-Industry.png --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=\"Sogemex Industry\" --version-string.ProductName=\"Sogemex Industry App\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . Sogemex_Industry_App --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=/home/nanon/Projets/VueJS/sogemex_electron/src/assets/sogemex-Industry.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "debian-installer": "electron-installer-debian --src release-builds/Sogemex_Industry_App-linux-x64/ --arch amd64 --config debian.json"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.11",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "translate": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-select": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "electron": "^6.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.4.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

**debian.json :**

```
{
    "dest": "release-builds/",
    "description": "Sogemex Industry work application",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "categories": [
      "Office"
    ],
    "lintianOverrides": [
      "changelog-file-missing-in-native-package"
    ]
}
```

[**Ubuntu Software view :**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkHff.png)

[**Terminal output when running `lintian release-builds/sogemex-industry-app_0.1.1_amd64.deb --no-tag-display-limit`:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8OQO.png)

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i finally solved my problem. This [github topic](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-debian/issues/187) put me on the way saying that the problem was not at the debian installer creation but in the way the application was packaged.

After that i realized that instead of using **electron-packager**, run `npm run electron:build` was also creating a package of my application named **linux-unpacked** in the **dist_electron** folder. When i tryed to use it as package to create my installer, **electron-installer-debian** specified me that some files where missing, LICENSE and version (***version*** *contain the electron version. I don't know if that is a rule but that is what mine contain*).

So i just added them and my installer was created and my software was finally able to be launch on the computer.